# Reload Just the Main Activity not the Launcher Activity

Tags: android, android-activity, android-manifest

I'm using this code to refresh MainActivity.java when a Refresh button is pressed.

```
      Intent intent = getIntent();
        finish();
        startActivity(intent);
```

MainActivity.java has the category default and there is another Launcher activity. So whenever I press the Refresh button the Launcher Activity also starts again. I only need to start the MainActivity class. Below is the manifest

```
   <application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/play_icon"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/CustomActionBarTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.theanilpaudel.joshilo.FirstScreen"
        android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
        android:label="@string/app_name"

         >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.theanilpaudel.joshilo.MainActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAINACTIVITY" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Comment: Why are you completely destroying then recreating your Activity to refresh it? There is almost certainly a better way to update the content of your Activity or do whatever else you are attempting to accomplish.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for in this case is an explicit Intent that launches `MainActivity`.

You can do this like so:

```
Intent mainIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
startActivity(mainIntent);
```

This will ensure that the Intent *only* launches `MainActivity`.

However, I highly recommend re-evaluating why you need to completely restart the Activity to refresh it. There are much cheaper (faster and less resource intensive) methods of updating data displayed in an Activity.

Comment: can you tell me some of those better ways

Comment: Well you haven't described what you are trying to update, so it's difficult to say. If you are just updating text for example, you can just call `setText()` on your `TextView` to update the content. All Views can be updated after they are created.

Answer (score 0):

I guess I know the culprit. Try using the following code once.

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
startActivity(intent);
finish();
```

As far as I know `startActivity()` uses *context* to run. In case if you call `finish()` before `startActivity()` that may lead to destroy context of `MainActivity` and will get the application's context i.e. fires the activity with behavior `LAUNCHER` or `MAIN`.

```
<action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
<category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
```

Let me know if it helps or you still have difficulty reloading activity.

Cheers